# Count has_many records of query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

If I have a Model with a `has_many` relationship, how can I retrieve all of the records that all  of the records in my query point to?

Let's just say, buildings have a has_many relationship with rooms. Here's what I want to do:

```
Building.where(...query...).rooms.count
```

This is just an example. I might want to count them, or I might want an ActiveRecord of the rooms that belong to the buildings that match the query.

One way is this, but I'm wondering if there's a better way:

```
building_ids = Building.where(...query...).pluck(:id)
Room.where(building_id: building_ids).count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `select` instead of `pluck` will result in a single sql statement instead of two separate ones.

```
building_ids = Building.where(...).ids
Room.where(building_id: building_ids)
```

you can also use `join`

```
Room.joins(:building).where(building: { name: 'somename' })
```

Comment: Aha! My brain was beginning to go in this direction (since the Active Record I really want is of Rooms), but I was having trouble remembering how to use joins. I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the sum of the counter caches.

Add the counter cache colum in a migration:

```
add_column :buildings, :rooms_count, default: 0
```

Update the relation in Room:

```
belongs_to :building, counter_cache: true
```

Then you could do something like:

```
Building.sum(:rooms_count)
```

That'll avoid n+1 queries

More details here https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html

Comment: Like I mentioned though, this is just an example, and I really want access to the ActiveRecord for the Rooms. What I really want to do is something more like `Building.where(paint: red).rooms.sum(:chairs)`

Comment: I guess getting the building_ids really is the best way. I just thought I remembered a way to do it in one line.

Comment: Okay! In that case Eyeslandic's ansers fits that I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/63292742/4701098